# Jquery next not finding the next div?

Tags: jquery

I have this HTML structure

```
<img  width="25" height="25" src=/data/apple_logo.jpg alt=Chocolate />      
  <input class="cake_checkboxes" style="vertical-align: bottom;"  type="checkbox" name="option[232][]" value="23" id="option-value-23" />
  <label for="option-value-23"> Chocolate</label>
  <br />
<div style='display:none;' class="quantity">
......
```

If i do

```
$('.cake_checkboxes:first').next('div')
```

or

```
$('.cake_checkboxes:first').next('.quantity')
```

I get an empty value returned but if i do this

```
$('.cake_checkboxes:first').next().next().next()
```

I get the div i need ...any ideas on what is wrong or if there is a way to traverse down like the jquery [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method traverses up

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next) only returns the next element in the DOM if it matches the selector, otherwise it returns and empty object. So the only thing you could search for using `next()` is the `<label>`. Use this instead:

```
$('.cake_checkboxes:first').nextAll('.quantity').first()
```

jQuery Docs: [`nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll)

Comment: I thought `nextUntil()` does NOT include the element that was matched?

Comment: Where possible, also start a class selector with an element. this will speed it up in browsers who don't have built in getElementsByClassName so in your case input.cake_checkboxes

Comment: @Harry: True, however that will slow it down in browsers that DO support `getElementsByClassName`. I guess it just depends on which browser you cater to.

Comment: For me the small hit to browsers which do support getElementsByClassName is far outweighed by browsers who don't support it checking every element in the DOM for that class. Maybe a containing element with an id and a #id .cake_checkboxes selector would be a happy medium

Answer (score 3):

siblings also work here

```
$('.cake_checkboxes:first').siblings('.quantity')
```

Comment: siblings is slightly slower as it also checks any elements before the starting point. nextAll only checks elements after.